# Accidentally Pasted Beyond Origin in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, error, eda

I'm new in Altium and I accidentally pasted some pads and components(the ones at the bottom corner) from another pcb file but I wasn't aware of it at first because it didn't show on the sheet on the 2D view. Is there anyway that this can be fixed/removed?

I'm afraid this will mess up in the manufacturing process since it can be seen on the Gerber file.Or will this not affect the design at all since it is beyond the sheet? Thanks guys!

[image: Error/Bug not seen on 2d view]
Error/Bug not seen on 2d view
[image: Paste Error/Bug in 3D View]
Paste Error/Bug in 3D View
[image: Error/Bug in Gerber]
Paste Error/Bug in Gerber

Comment: I would not take the risk and revert to a prior version if you can’t delete those extra pads etc

Comment: You can send a mail to your manufacturer and explain the issue, it is not the most elegant, but normally they won't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 (the quick way):

1. Make all layers visible: Layser Set(LS): All layers
2. Select everything outside the extremeties of your board. (Keys: S O) then draw a box round your work area
3. Go to PCB List view.  Filter on selected
4. Highlight and Delete selected.

If you don't want to delete stuff you can always move it, (Keys: E M S)

Note: In AD18 or Nexus you will need to ensure you are not pre-filtering anything.

Method 2 (the slow way):

1. Set the origin (Keys: E O S) beyond the bottom left edge of your work area
2. Go to PCB Filter view
3. Enter filter (X1 < 0) or (X2 < 0) or (Y1 < 0) or (Y2 < 0)
4. select matching and apply.
5. Press delete button
6. Set the origin (Keys: E O S) beyond the top right edge of your work area
7. Go to PCB Filter view
8. Enter filter (X1 > 0) or (X2 > 0) or (Y1 > 0) or (Y2 > 0)
9. select matching and apply.
10. Press delete button